# How to determine in which direction a bitmap has to be rotated?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, android-canvas

How can I determine in which direction and how far I have to rotate the image? I use Android Canvas to draw the line and the arrow image.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(arrow_direction, leftpos,rightpos,null);
```

The image is always shown as it is. The image shows clearly that I have to rotate it 90 degree to the left.

I know I can rotate the image with

```
Matrix rotator = new Matrix();    
rotator.reset();
rotator.postRotate(degree);
```

But I don't know how to calculate the value for degree to rotate the arrow? I know only the coordinates of the two red points. So I think it might be possible to calculate it with this two points, but I don't know how.
In another way how can determine on which side of the image is the end point of the line? In the example it is on the right side, therefore I know that I have to rotate the image -90 degree.

[image]